# How to store data where various subcategories have specific columns?

Tags: mysql, database-design, subtypes

I'm new to database designing. I'll use MySQL and PHP. I'm designing a database in which I have a lot of categories and subcategories like given below:

```
Product Table
  p_id
  p_title
  category_id   F Key

Category_Table
  c_id
  c_name

Sub_category_Table
  sc_id
  sc_name
  c_id      F Key
```

Now, the problem is, for example, I have 8 categories and about 60 subcategories with some common column names and some quite different like this:

```
Vehicle                           // a category
  Car                          // subcategory
      id,
      cat_id
      brand_id
      model
      price
      year
      insurance_validity_date
      fuel_type

  Motorcycle                          // subcategory
      id
      cat_id
      brand_id
      model
      price
      year

  Bus/Lorry                          // subcategory
      id
      cat_id
      brand_id
      model
      price
      year
      insurance_validity_date
      fuel_type
```

Now I'm merging all the same columns in one table named `Vehicle` and making a new table named `car` to store the `insurance_validity_date`, `fuel_type` columns and no table for Motorcycles at all like this:

```
Vehicle (= Motorcycle)                           // a category
      id
      cat_id
      brand_id
      model
      price
      year

 Car/Bus                          // subcategory
      id
      insurance_validity_date
      fuel_type
      vehicle_id
```

It means there is no need to create a `Motorcycle` table, and `Car` and `Bus` will be stored in a single table. Is it right?

1. Motorcycle is a Vehicle
2. Car is a Vehicle
3. Bus is a Vehicle

The `vehicle_id` value will identify whether the record is a bus or a car.

---

Here is a similar example for users. I've three types of users: admin, registered and guest with the following schema:

```
Person
  user
      id
      name
      user_name
      email
      contact_no
      password
      no_of_log_ins
      last_login_time
      registration_date
      city
      user_role_or_type_id

  business_owner
      id
      name
      user_name
      company_business_shop_name
      email
      contact_no
      address
      password
      no_of_log_ins
      last_login_time
      registration_date
      city
      user_role_or_type_id

   guest
      id
      name
      email
      contact_no
      city
      user_role_or_type_id

   admin
      id
      name
      email
      contact_no
      password
      no_of_logins
      last_login_time
      user_role_or_type_id
```

Now I'm merging all the same columns in one table named `Person` and modifying `user`, `guest` and `admin` to have type-specific columns like this:

```
Person (= Guest)
      id
      name
      email
      contact_no
      city
      user_role_or_type_id

   guest
     id
     Person_id

   registered_user (or admin)
      id
      person_id
      user_name
      password
      no_of_logins
      last_login_time

          admin
             id
             registered_user_id

          user                              
             id
             registration_date
             registered_user_id

          business_owner
             company_business_shop_name
             address
             registered_user_id
```

This model means:

1. Guest is a Person
2. Registered user is a Person
   (i)   user is a Registered User
   (ii)  business_owner is a Registered User

That's all what I think a solution for me. Is it a good solution? Would it not degrade the performance? Should I look for any other solution? I need some guidance.